# Set "Remote desktop" host server remotely

Tags: configuration, remote-desktop

When you want to set a server to accept "Remote Desktop" connections, you do:
System \ Preferences \ Remote Desktop

The thing is I just have a ssh connection to the server for now. How do you set it using only the command line ?

Comment: Actually I found out that when the host restart, vino-server is not restarted by default, eventhough the settings at System \ Preferences \ Remote Desktop are correct. If you unset and reset, it restarts vino-server

Comment: you can also do "/usr/lib/vino/vino-server --sm-disable" on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work with a normal installation:

ssh to your remote machine, with X forwarding turned on

```
ssh -X servername
```

Then run `vino-preferences`

Alternatively, set the gconf keys from the command line with gconftool :

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
```

You can see the other remote_access keys with this command :

```
gconftool-2 -a /desktop/gnome/remote_access
```

If your server isn't started remotely, start it with

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

There's more info in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline/22354#22354).

Answer (score 4):

Install `x11vnc` on the remote computer and then punch something like this in on your local computer:

```
ssh user@host -L 5900:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -display :0 -noxdamage"
```

Then connect to localhost on your local computer with your VNC client. The local port 5900 will be tunnelled over the SSH connection (which is now running `x11vnc`).

Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming then that you have the openssh server installed in the server. So from a client do this:

ssh USER@SERVER. For example: `ssh cyrex@askubuntu.com` This is the **simple** way of ssh to connect.

The user HAS to have ssh permission in the server and must also be available in the server of course.

Comment: I want to start a "Remote desktop Viewer" through VNC, but I have to set up "System \ Preferences \ Remote Desktop" on the host server. Which file on the server need to be changed ?

Comment: i was going to type what Oli said above. Which was my first guess after you explain the way to connect. Am going to edit this post with other options but Oli is right with x11vnc.