# How to change port number in vino?

Tags: 11.10, vino

How to change port number in vino Ubuntu 11.10?

Cannot find option to change from port 5900 on vino vnc 'remote desktop' window, nor can I find it via `gconf-editor` as was available in previous Ubuntu version.

Comment: You *can* install `gconf-editor`.

Comment: I did add it, however there are not options for alternative port as in previous versions of ubuntu

Answer (score 11):

Install dconf-editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Press alt+f2 and type `dconf-editor`

Navigate to `desktop`>`gnome`>`remote access` and change your port there, **don't forget to tick the `use-alternative-port` option so that vino uses the one you set**:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats a smart way.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10 dconf-editor was set, but vino did not use the value set.

Answer (score 2):

Failing finding the configuration, you could set up iptables (the kernel-level firewall) to redirect another port to 5900 using something like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 59000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5900
```

Port 5900 would still be used for hosting it but so would port 59000.

I'm not sure if that it acceptable for your problem or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is a brainstorm idea that was closed because it was thought of as a bug report: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25109/

Here is another question regarding this and the second answer mentions how to do it but I recommend using iptables: [Enable remote VNC from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline)

UPDATE - As mentioned by the answer from Oli that would be the way to do it until the `vino-preferences` readds the option again.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 14.10, gconf-editor was required. dconf-editor set a value, but it was not used, and displayed as 0 (5900) in gconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
gconf-editor
```

[image]