# Black screen when accessing Ubuntu remote host via VNC and vino-server

Tags: command-line, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc, vino

I have a headless server and I am trying to setup a VNC connection in order to access it with a GUI. Now I have only root access via ssh.

I have followed most of the instructions given here [Enable remote VNC from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline). After a lot of problems I reached to a point where vino-server is able to run, but when I connect with a VNC client I reach a black screen.

So far I installed vino and ubuntu-desktop. After that I did the following commands:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type=bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino erequire-encryption false
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
```

With `vino-preferences` I clicked to allow to view and control the desktop. Also unchecked the confirm incoming connections.

I run vino with `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`and this is the output:

```
(vino-server:8140): EggSMClient-CRITICAL **: egg_sm_client_set_mode: assertion 'global_client == NULL || global_client_mode == EGG_SM_CLIENT_MODE_DISABLED' failed

** (vino-server:8140): WARNING **: Your XServer does not support the XTest extension - remote desktop access will be view-only

25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Autoprobing TCP port in (all) network interface
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Autoprobing selected port 5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Clearing securityTypes
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Clearing securityTypes
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Clearing securityTypes
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Clearing authTypes
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
25/06/2014 02:09:24 PM Advertising security type: 'No Authentication' (1)
```

Following some google search for the black screen problem I also installed the gnome-core and appended the .vnc/Xstartup file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session –session=gnome-classic &
gnome-panel&

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
```

Comment: Did you happen to fix this problem?