# configure 'other users are able to view my desktop' via command line

Tags: vnc, remote, gconf, vino

I am trying to get vino-server to work via ssh on an Ubuntu 17.04 machine. Specifically, I want to set the option that 'other users are able to view my desktop'. Ubuntu's [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers#vino) on vino states to set this option via the gui (i.e., Menu > Settings > Remote Access). However, I cannot access the gui on my remote machine, so I am looking for a configuration file where I can set this 'other users able to view my desktop' option. Does anyone know which configuration file this is?

An older [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline) from 2010 states that I can access this configuration file via ~/.gconf, however there is no ~/.gconf folder, nor a gconf.xml file anywhere on my machine.

Comment: Your answer is here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219600

Comment: See this, about remote config https://access.redhat.com/solutions/346033

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?
`gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/remote_access/enabled true`

Source: https://linuxexplore.com/tips-tricks/configure-remote-desktop-from-command-line/

Not sure where these things are actually stored, but gconf is generally modified by issuing commands via gconftool or some other CLI tool.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant settings are not contained in a configuration file as such - but in the dconf database associated with the remote desktop session that you are trying to view. You can modify them using either

```
DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.Vino view-only 'true'
DISPLAY=:0 gsettings set org.gnome.Vino enabled 'true'
```

or

```
DISPLAY=:0 dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/view-only  'true'
DISPLAY=:0 dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/enabled 'true'
```

(adjust the `DISPLAY` value if `:0` is not your remote physical desktop).