# Ubuntu remote desktop from another ubuntu

Tags: remote-access

I would like to know how to take remote desktop control from my ubuntu machine to another Ubuntu machine. Totally I have 80 plus Ubuntu users and if I have remote desktop it will be easy for us to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1):

## SSH server

You can install an ssh server for example `openssh-server` in the Ubuntu systems that you want to access remotely. Then you can connect via `ssh` to run programs remotely and via `sftp` or `rsync` to transfer files.

See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

If you use key authentication, you need not use password to log in, which makes things faster and easier. Then you can also disable password authentication, which makes things safer.

### Example

**Shellscripts**

You can use a shellscript similar to this to transfer files,

`send-data-to-computer-x`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <user@ip-adress>"
  exit
fi

echo "$0 $1 sending data via rsync"

rsync -Hav directory-to-transfer "$1":/home/${1%\@*}
```

You can use a shellscript similar to this to do things at the remote computer, in this example check with `md5sum` that the transfer was successful,

`do-things-at-computer-x`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 <user@ip-adress>"
  exit
fi

echo "$0 $1 running commands via ssh"

ssh "$1" "cd directory-to-transfer;grep -v ' .md5sum\.txt$' md5sum.txt | md5sum -c"
```

These shellscripts can be **run from a master shellscript** with `user@ip-adress` specified for every target computer in order to make things convenient.

**Dialogue**

```
$ ./send-data-to-computer-x  sudodus@192.168.0.4
./send-data-to-computer-x sudodus@192.168.0.4 sending data via rsync
sudodus@192.168.0.4's password: 
sending incremental file list
directory-to-transfer/
directory-to-transfer/01-ssh-connect-to-server.png
directory-to-transfer/02-ssh-cant-verify-the-identity-first-time.png
directory-to-transfer/03-ssh-enter-password.png
directory-to-transfer/04-ssh-logged-into-the-server.png
directory-to-transfer/05-ssh-baobab-in-server.png
directory-to-transfer/do-things-at-computer-x
directory-to-transfer/md5sum.txt
directory-to-transfer/send-data-to-computer-x

sent 1,653,050 bytes  received 172 bytes  300,585.82 bytes/sec
total size is 1,651,897  speedup is 1.00
$ ./do-things-at-computer-x  sudodus@192.168.0.4
./do-things-at-computer-x sudodus@192.168.0.4 running commands via ssh
sudodus@192.168.0.4's password: 
01-ssh-connect-to-server.png: OK
02-ssh-cant-verify-the-identity-first-time.png: OK
03-ssh-enter-password.png: OK
04-ssh-logged-into-the-server.png: OK
05-ssh-baobab-in-server.png: OK
do-things-at-computer-x: OK
send-data-to-computer-x: OK
$
```

### More tips

The following link will add some detailed tips, that might be useful

[What is the simplest way to have remote GUI access to Ubuntu 16.04 “server” from Ubuntu 16.04 “desktop”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886313/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-have-remote-gui-access-to-ubuntu-16-04-server-from/886398#886398)

Answer (score 1):

Use Vino, or deploy another VNC server to the users: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers

And you are going to need to start it up on the target machines:
[Enable remote VNC from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline#22354)

Then you can use any VNC client from your location to connect to the remote machine.