# For reasons of unknown cause, a huge size of syslog continues to be created

Tags: 18.04, syslog

I am struggling with huge syslog files that occur frequently.
In only 24 hours, 740G files were created, and a lots of addresses were recorded.

Even similar domains and ip addresses appear repeatedly.

syslog, syslog.1, syslog.2.gz, syslog.3.gz, syslog.4.gz, syslog.5.gz, syslog.6.gz, syslog.7.gz
Eight files have been created, all of which are 1.5T in size.

These huge files have filled the root mount, and they continue to produce the following errors.

`bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`

I'm sharing the log contents.

```
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      221.165.214.185
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      106.246.244.122
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb691.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      106.246.244.122
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      video.nowfc.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      45.12.6.88
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mitziejamelymb69.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: message repeated 2 times: [ 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      176.111.173.12]
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      106.246.244.122
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      mandimichaelibws961.example.com
Oct 28 00:41:45 bio507-3 vino-server[4958]: 28/10/2021 00h 41m 45s      haumea.vds.sh
```

I doubt that this is related to hacking.

What do experts think?

I know that there is no problem with the system even if I delete these files, but I want to know the cause of the huge log file that continues to be generated even after deletion.

I am using Ubuntu version 18.04.

I don't want these huge log files to be created anymore.
If hacking or other problems are the cause, please advise on how to solve them.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1364457/1222991) and followed the suggestion at the bottom to limit the log file size? 

Comment: vino-server is logging everything to it (actions, warnings,errors and critical notes) so change it to have it log for errors and critital only.

Comment: @Rinzwind I would like to change that. Do you know how can I change it?

Comment: @matigo The way to limit the size can prevent errors, but I don't think we can find the cause of the huge log file. Is there any additional process I have to do to find out the cause?

Comment: My prev. comment might be wrong: it is probably not vino itself but the fact connections are made to your system that triggers this (I am used to see these in access,log on apache).  It is indeed not a hacker but it is a ddos attack; probably automated and not targeted at you specifically. The fix is likely outside of Ubuntu (block IPs not yours at your router for instance). A firewall on Ubuntu can block this too but the connection attempts are still going to reach your server clogging your internet line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely being attacked.
Are you behind some kind of firewall?

You better use VNC via SSH tunneling.

**Related**

1. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362684
2. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/do-you-know-what-the-following-in-syslog-means/111348
3. [Is my Vino server being attacked?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067305/is-my-vino-server-being-attacked)

Comment: Thank you.
Your advice was very helpful.

I got a big hint through link #2.
I saw https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2362684 among the comments in the post, and I saw "world-reachable IP address (172.x.x.x)" in the article and checked it with my computer.

As a result of checking, it was confirmed that the Docker installed on the computer was assigned a 172.x.x.x IP address, and the docker was stopped. Since then, logs have no longer accumulated.

Thanks once again.

Comment: @hYEOnOOnull - Great! Your response is very good, and uncommon: Using the suggestions to further dig into the problem, finding the solution, and posting feedback with details.
(I see all too often OPs waiting for a step-by-step list of instructions on what to do, with no signs of effort.)
Cheers for that!