# vino: no such schema of "org.gnome.Vino"?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

This is more a follow-up question regarding this issue (e.g., [Enable remote VNC from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline)). I am using desktop sharing of Ubuntu 18.04 (without vino server). For remote access from another Ubuntu via remmina, it's working fine. But when I try VNC client from Mac, it complains about encryption level.

I try "gsettings set org.gnome.Vino ..." on the server, but it says no such schema.

Comment: Do you have `vino` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.gnome.Vino) installed?

Comment: @N0rbert, No, I only change settings of a fresh new 18.04 and start to use remote desktop. Do I need to install vino package (not vino server)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this file is contained in this package...

Comment: Looks like I need to, following the discussion here: https://websiteforstudents.com/access-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta-desktop-via-vnc-from-windows-machines/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to install `vino` package with

```
sudo apt install vino
```

as it contains [needed file](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.gnome.Vino).