# Make Screen Sharing Active at Ubuntu 20.04 using CLI

Tags: command-line, 20.04, screen, gui, sharing

I want to build a script that will make the "screen sharing" through CLI (I have to do it on a lot of computers in the future and I want to add such script to another scripts that will configure the OS),

I currently know how to do it through the GUI: https://linuxhint.com/enable-screen-sharing-ubuntu/

How can I use CLI to make this configuration:
[using GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cup7M.png)

I don't find on the NET any bunch of instructions that can make it...
the most close answer to my question i found is this: [Enable remote VNC from the commandline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4474/enable-remote-vnc-from-the-commandline)
but it still not triggers the sharing at the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

One step that is not often mentioned is that you need to enable auto login, you can do so by editing the following file:

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

And adding the following lines (or modifying existing vales):

```
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=myuser
```

Also sharing has to be enabled for specific network connection(s).

Find the current active "Network Manager" connection UUID via:

```
nmcli con
```

You can see the currently shared networks via:

```
dconf read /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sharing/vino-server/enabled-connections
```

If the UUID for the network connection to want to desktop share over is not there add it as follows:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/sharing/vino-server/enabled-connections "['2bae8cfd-0d24-3e0d-ab84-4ae606e11df7']"
```

Set the password:

```
PASSWORD="passwordgoeshere"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/vnc-password \"\'$(echo -n $PASSWORD | base64)\'\"
```

Set remaining sharing settings:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/authentication-methods "['vnc']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/prompt-enabled false
```